# How I can create a camel globalObject?

Tags: apache-camel

I need a global `Object` for all routes, processes and Components. In this global `Object` I would save configuration parameters. But I don't know how and where I can set a global `Object`, and how I can read it in my own process and my own components.

I create the camel Context in Spring and have a `RouteBuilder` to build my routes.

Thank you

Comment: Erm, you might want to use Spring to inject a Properties object... Or use a ProperyPlaceholderConfigurer right away? Like for anything else?

Comment: Where is the different? What is better to use? I want to have a Object, where I can access from overall! I am new to Apache Camel so I don't know, what is better

Comment: This has nothing to do with Camel, but with Spring. The Properties object may be a bit more flexible, whereas a Spring configurer is easier to setup up. There are literally thousands of tutorials and blog posts around. Google it. Then, you can simply inject the values needed.

Comment: You can use the Camel Properties component to access configuration parameters as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to setup your route, then you may use `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`, see [here](http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-use-spring-property-placeholder-with-camel-xml.html):

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"/>

<camelContext xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/camel/schema/spring">
  <route>
    <from uri="activemq:${someQueueName}"/>
    <to uri="mock:results"/>
  </route>
</camelContext>
```

Alternatively, you may use `ApplicationContextRegistry` that allows you to look up beans in the Spring `ApplicationContext`. This implementation is automatically used when you’re using Camel in a Spring environment, see [here](http://camel.apache.org/registry.html). E.g., access the registry as follows:

```
String myValue = exchange.getContext().getRegistry().lookupByNameAndType("myKey", String.class);
```